# PHP PayPal API: set shipping costs and optional discounts to the order

Tags: php, paypal

I have some trouble setting the shipping cost and discounts to a paypal order using the REST API.

Here https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/Amount.php I see the last method being `setDetails()` so I used the `Details()` class to set the shipping, then I called `$amount->setDetails($details)` but every time I get a `400 error response`.

Here is the code

```
// $shipping_cost = 10; $subtotal = 100; $total = 110;
$details = new Details();
$details->setShipping($shipping_cost);
$details->setShipping($subtotal);

// Specify the payment amount.
$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency($currency);
$amount->setTotal($total);
$amount->setDetails($details);
```

Just to be sure, if I remove the `$details` part it works and I get redirected to paypal, but the shipping cost is not showing up.

This error is because the total is somehow wrong and it only works when the shipping cost is 0.

I also tried setting `$amount->setTotal($total);` but with no luck.

This is the exact same code as it is on the documentation site but it doesn't work.

Please help me solve it, I'm fighting with this for 2 days and their documentation doesn't help me at all.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting a 400 response code because the *subtotal, tax and shipping* are not adding up to the **total** amount.

Try declaring the below variables for testing purposes:

```
$subtotal = 100; // These are just test values for this example
$ship_tax = 10;
$ship_cost = 10;
$currency = 'USD';
$total = $subtotal + $ship_tax + $ship_cost;
```

And then:

```
$details = new Details();
$details->setSubtotal($subtotal)
        ->setTax($ship_tax)
        ->setShipping($ship_cost);

$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency($currency)
       ->setTotal($total) 
       ->setDetails($details);
```